# SMS sending in PHP ,without header() function

Tags: php, sms-gateway, head

I am sending SMS from my bus ticketing site. The SMS can be send as follows :

```
header('Location: http://alerts.icisms.in/api/web2sms.php?workingkey=XXXXXX&sender=ABCD&to='.$number.'&message='.$message);
```

But I need to return to my own site.How can I accomplish this?

Comment: cURL http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Comment: @bažmegakapa — iframes suffer form the same security problem as the approach in the question does: They leak the key to the user.

Comment: @Quentin Sure, right... Hasn't read the whole thing cautiously enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use cURL or a simple file()/file_get_contents() call.

```
//call
$url = 'http://alerts.icisms.in/api/web2sms.php?workingkey=XXXXXX&sender=ABCD&to=' . $number . '&message=' . $message;

//do call
file($url);
```

Then set your header location to your site.

Comment: Ok..its working but not 100% ! because if `$message = 'Dear Mr. XXXX XXXXX,etc etc...'` only `Mr` is coming to mobile !

Comment: @AssamGuy does your SMS provider have an API? Replace `$message` above with `urlencode($message)`

Answer (score 6):

You make an HTTP request using PHP (e.g. with the [cURL](http://php.net/curl) library or [fopen](http://php.net/fopen)).

You don't give your key to the user and ask their browser to make the request to the API.

Comment: Thanks for your response. How can I do it using fopen() ?  `$handle = fopen("http://alerts.icisms.in/api/web2sms.php?workingkey=XXXXXX&sender=ABCD&to=".$number."&message=".$message", "w");` I am wrong?

Answer (score 3):

From the looks of it you would just be able to do a simple request to this page.

You can achieve this using either the [CURL functions](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-init.php) or simply using [file_get_contents](https://www.php.net/file_get_contents) to perform a single GET request.

By using `header` you're redirecting the client which is unnecessary and potentially unsecure. EDIT: Scrap potentially, you've got an authentication key in there so giving that to your third-party users is not a good thing to do at all.